# reading from a json file using fscanf() in c

Tags: c, file-io

I was wondering if someone could explain why it is reading zeros and how to fix it

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  FILE* f = fopen("text.json","r");
  int l,x=0;
  fscanf(f,"%d %d ",&l,&x);
  printf("%d %d ",l,x);
 
  return 0;
}
```

my text.json:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

when run this prints two 0s. I don't really understand why or how I would make it print numbers.

Comment: [man fscanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf): `If processing of a directive fails, no further input is read`. In your case `%d` tells `fscanf` to match an integer as the next input. Since the next input is `[` and not an integer the directive fails and no further input is read.

Comment: Try `if (fscanf(f," [%d ,%d ,",&l,&x) == 2) success();`.

Answer (score 0):

use [fread](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) instead of `fscanf`

`char buffer[1024] = {0};`

`fread(buffer, 1024, 1, f);`